# difference between set @flag =1 and set @@flag = 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi What is the difference between

`set @flag=1` and `set @@flag = 1` in SQL Server?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing. Some in-built functions have names that start with double at signs `@@` as a convention. To avoid confusion it is often recommended that you do not use names that start with `@@`.

Source: [MSDN: Using Identifiers - Rules for Regular Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962(SQL.80).aspx).